# Question about variance-covariance matrix structure of random effects parameters

Tags: mixed-model, covariance-matrix

I'm reading [*Introduction to Linear Mixed Models*](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/introduction-to-linear-mixed-models/) and in the example of $J=407$ doctors, it says:

> $u$ is distributed as normal with mean zero and variance $G$ where $u$ is a $J \times 1$ vector.

In the example, we only consider a single random intercept. It goes on to say:

> Because our example only had a random intercept, $G$ is just a $1 \times 1$ matrix.

But I'm confused. Since $u$ is a $J \times 1$ vector, shouldn't $G$ be a $J \times J$ variance covariance matrix of the intercept? Or is there an assumption that the intercept for each doctor is independent? Is $u$ referring to $u_j$ for doctor $j$? Thanks.